# Spring testing annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been working on a personal project very recently and looking at my test file I realized I have some regarding spring annotations:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BookingServicesTests {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private BookingResource bookingController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(bookingController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ConflictExceptionController())
                .build();
    }

   ...
}
```

So the thing is that `@SpringBootTest` is made to test your application using real HTTP methods. But in my `setup` method I included a `MockMvcBuilders` statement, which is a standalone test (no server and no application context).

My question is:

1. Are those elements incompatible?
2. One element obfuscate the other? This is: by using `MockMvcBuilder` can I get rid of `@SpringBootTest`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one or the other, not both. You are only allowed one JUnit's `@runwith()` and the value you pass in, whether it be `SpringRunner.class` or `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`, has very different behaviors.

So the code you posted is incorrect as `@SpringBootTest` will try to load the application context when your test class is "running with `MockitoJUnitRunner`". Therefore `@SpringBootTest` should be used along with `@runWith(SpringRunner.class)`, as such

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookingResource.class) // multiple controller class could go here
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BookingServicesTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    ...
}
```

Notice how I replace `@SpringBootTest()` with `@WebMvcTest()`. This is because `@WebMvcTest()` only scans components that are `@Controller` and loads configuration for the web layer, whereas `@SpringBootTest()` does so for the entire application.

Or what you did with Mockito without Spring:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BookingServicesTests {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private BookingResource bookingController;
    ...
}
```